HoloISO/Archlinux Running pacman -Syu(u) results in the next boot becoming an endless black screen
I have been running both pacman -Syu and -Syuu with the following packages:

glibc make icu qt6-base linux-firmware pcaman-contrib
archlinux-contrib gcc-libs sh python  wireplumber pipewire lha
base-devel fwupd linux-firmware-qlogic linux-firmware-bnx2x
linux-firmware-liquidio linux-firmware-mellanox linux-firmware-nfp

The subsequent log gives no errors, only warnings. One is related to consolefonts in the mkinitcpio file. I've just been removing that element from the file and it doesn't seem to result in further problems.
Another set of warnings relates to the AUR packages mentioned here https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mkinitcpio#Possibly_missing_firmware_for_module_XXXX. I've been installing them after the first -Syu and then re-runnign -Syu afterwards to check if they need any packages. However, every time I install  upd72020x-fw, it always comes empty. I have no idea why or what effect this has.
The last set of warnings mention permissions being different on the system than the package apparently wants. I've tried pre-empting these by manually changing the permissions using chmod to the numbers stated, but that just makes other packages warn about differing permissions.
I've tried running -Syu without the extra packages, which leads to the same result. I've been saying yes to all of the "replace (package) with extra_main/(package)5" requests. If I do need to say no to them every time, is there a way to do so without having to type n for each?
The system works fine if I don't use -Syu, but that limits what I can do with it severely.
Processors: 4 x AMD Ryzen 3 2300X Quad-Core Processor
Memory: 7.7 GiB
Graphic Processor: AMD Radeon RX 570

Is the screen still black if you open a text console with Ctrl + Alt + F2?

@eyoung100 No I am able access that console. I may be able to log in, but the numbers on my keyboard recently broke so I can't enter my password and continue from there. What should I be doing once I log in?

Please add the output of a tool like lspci or lshw to your post.  I believe something in the set of packages you're trying to download/update is causing a driver issue.  HOPEFULLY, the information I requested will help us narrow down the package that's causing the issue.
